# Tentatively taking on a minhag or chumra

Tags: halacha, minhag, stringency-chumrah, civil-procedure

Noting that [doing a positive action three times constitues a vow or something akin to a vow](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64077/31534), what is the ideal way to tentatively take on a minhag (custom) or chumra (stringency)? Say a Sefardi is interested in growing and wearing peyot, and isn't sure still. They want to try it for a month or more.

What's the best way to do this? Stipulate from the start that this is non-binding (if so, how exactly)? Or take it on fully, and resort to *hatarat nedarim* (or whatever is needed) if they end up not wishing to proceed? Or something else?

Comment: Every year many say "I don't regret having done many good deeds only having accepted to do them in a language of neder shvua issur cherem konam shamta or arur"

Comment: The question is interesting but it seems your premise is that doing something for a month might obligate you going forward unless you do/say something. Could you source that?

Comment: does not doing it 3 times constitute the undoing of this chumra...?

Comment: Regarding the linked question ("What is the source for the idea that doing some good thing 3 times constitutes a vow?"): Doesn't [David Kenner's answer there](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/64103/1368) provide an answer to your question (at least _vis-à-vis_ taking on a chumra/stringency)?

Comment: @TamirEvan indeed it does! Thanks for pointing it out to me. I think this question could potentially be closed as a dupe for that reason?

Comment: @RabbiKaii "_I think this question could potentially be closed as a dupe for that reason?_" I don't think so: That question is asking for the _source_ of the idea that doing something three times constitutes a vow (or something akin to a vow), whereas you're asking for _how to avoid_ it. The answer I linked just happened to answer your question, as well. The [currently] two other answers there, by contrast, don't answer your question (Aaron's answer dismisses your premise as a recent innovation, and Scimonster's simply brings the earliest(?) mention of it).

Answer (score 1):

Before doing it, verbalize that you are doing it bli neder

See Shulchan Aruch Yoreh De’ah 214.1

Comment: Every time? Is this better than doing it properly and relying on hatarat nedarim?

Comment: @RabbiK what is not proper about doing it without a neder?

Comment: @DoubleAA I meant doing it _without_ bli neder in advance

Comment: @RabbiK yes, and why is that "proper"

Comment: A source would greatly improve this answer

Comment: @DoubleAA the action in and of itself is completely proper, but it is lacking commitment

Comment: @Rabbi Kai, See Shulchan Aruch Yoreh De’ah 214.1. I added it to the answer