binding minhagim
If one says or thinks that he wants to adopt a certain way. Then, some time later (days or weeks), he performs that way with no recollection of his previous mindset or wording (3 times if necessary) just like a regular person doing something for any given reason.
Is that considered a binding minhag (or shita in halachah view)?

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

It is likely this depends heavily on what happened at the beginning. Saying is one thing, thinking is another, the mindset when saying is relevant, whether or not one said "bli neder", etc. This sort of question is likely to be much better answered by a Rav who can ask the relevant question to get the full context

Possible duplicate: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64077/what-is-the-source-for-the-idea-that-doing-some-good-thing-3-times-constitutes-a
