Translating the vow/minhag
If one mentions that he wants to act according to a specific shita (not intending to make a neder), then acts according to that shita, is that considered an act that now becomes binding to him?
(regarding doing something 1 time with intention or 3 times with no intention).

Didn't you ask this question, or a very similar one, already?

@C L it would be very helpful if you could provide a specific example of the kind of "act" that you have in mind. Without an example I cannot see any way to provide an answer.

Is this different from https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/142471/binding-minhagim ?

Sorry for any misunderstanding. the first question was to wether or not the mindset (virble or non virble) need to be at the time of action. or even alot prior can make the action binding. This question is what can these binding acts take effect on. is it specificly on stringecys upon yourself, or even to bind yourself to a specicfic persons (rav/posek) shitos in halachah that once you do like him once you are now bound to his psak/shitos... (assuming your mindset was to go according to that  rav/posek etc.)?
